# React Multi Step Form Validation on "onBlur", "onChange" and moving to next step

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, forms, validation

I'm running field level validation on "onBlur" & "onChange" this is working as expected,
But while clicking the "Next" button without filling it's not triggering all field-level validations at one go.

Case 1: If I'm enabling autofocus to 1st field and click "Next" without filling onBlur event is triggered and It's showing a username field error. If I'm clicking the "Next" second time it's showing all the field errors.

Case 2: autofocus disabled and click "Next" without filling, It's validating and updating the state but not reflecting in DOM, form is moving to the next step.

```js
const UserDetails = ({ nextStep, handleChange, values }) => {
  const fields = ['email', 'username', 'password']
  const Continue = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    nextStep(fields);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <form>
        <input
          type='text'
          name='email'
          placeholder="Email Address"
          id='email'
          value={values.email}
          onChange={handleChange('email')}
          onBlur={handleChange('email')}
          autoFocus={true} // set false to replicate case 2
        />
        <p
          style={{ display: values.emailIsValid ? 'block' : 'none' }}
        > {values.emailIsValid}
        </p> <br></br>
        <input
          type='text'
          name='username'
          placeholder="Username"
          id='usernaem'
          value={values.username}
          onChange={handleChange('username')}
          onBlur={handleChange('username')}
          autoFocus={false}
        />
        <p
          style={{ display: values.usernameIsValid ? 'block' : 'none' }}
        > {values.usernameIsValid}
        </p> <br></br>
        <input
          type='text'
          placeholder="Password"
          name='password'
          id='password'
          value={values.password}
          onChange={handleChange('password')}
          onBlur={handleChange('password')}
          autoFocus={false}
        />
        <p
          style={{ display: values.passwordIsValid ? 'block' : 'none' }}
        > {values.passwordIsValid}
        </p> <br></br>
        <button onClick={Continue}>Next</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}

const Success = ({ prevStep }) => {

  const Previous = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    prevStep();
  }

  return (
    <div>
      All set !!!
      <button onClick={Previous}>Back</button>
    </div>
  );
}

class Signup extends React.Component {

  state = {
    step: 1,
    email: '',
    emailIsValid: null,
    username: '',
    usernameIsValid: null,
    password: '',
    passwordIsValid: null,
  }

  prevStep = () => {
    const { step } = this.state;
    this.setState({ step: step - 1 });
  }

  isValid = (field) => {
    if (this.state[field] === '') {
      this.setState({ [field + 'IsValid']: 'Required !!!' });
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  }

  nextStep = (fields) => {
    fields.forEach(this.isValid);
    const { step } = this.state;
    if (fields.every(field => !this.state[field + 'IsValid'])) {
      this.setState({ step: step + 1 })
    }
  }

  handleChange = input => e => {
    if (e.target.value === '') {
      this.setState({ [input + 'IsValid']: 'Required !!!' });
    } else {
      this.setState({ [input]: e.target.value });
      this.setState({ [input + 'IsValid']: null });
    }
  }

  render() {
    const { step } = this.state;
    const { email, emailIsValid, username, usernameIsValid, password, passwordIsValid } = this.state;
    const values = { email, emailIsValid, username, usernameIsValid, password, passwordIsValid }

    switch (step) {
      case 1:
        return (
          <UserDetails
            nextStep={this.nextStep}
            handleChange={this.handleChange}
            values={values}
          />
        )
      case 2:
        return (
          <Success
            prevStep={this.prevStep}
          />
        )
      default:
      // do nothing
    }
  }
}

/*
 * Render the above component into the div#app
 */
ReactDOM.render(
  <Signup />,
  document.getElementById('app')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></app>
```

[Can also check it in codepen:](https://codepen.io/ramganez/pen/JjMdJGw)